# Aws setup Twitter as Identity Provider for User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I tried to add Twitter as Identity Provider for User Pool, I tried to add it Twitter as OpenID Connect with below information:

```
{   
  "client_id": "Consumer Key",  
  "client_secret": "Consumer Secret",  
  "authorize_scopes": "openid email profile",  
  "attributes_request_method": “POST”,  
  "oidc_issuer": "https://api.twitter.com/",  
  "authorize_url": "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",  
  "token_url": "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",  
  "attributes_url": "https://api.twitter.com",  
  "jwks_uri": "https://api.twitter.com"  
}
```

Below message is displayed.
Is there any missed setting? If you have any 
information, please teach me.
[image: Error]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also trying to figure out the same issue.